# Undefined method for object defined in controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a view with a form and a table that displays some data from the database. Whenever I try to access the object from my controller in my view I get `undefined method domain for "https://www.lookagain.co.uk/":String`. But if do `<%@savedHTML = ScrapedPage.all%>` everything works fine. I know the I should not do that in the view as it defeats to purpose of MVC but I don't seem to fin a fix.

View:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "masterstyles.css" %>




<% @url = 'default' %>
<%= form_for @url, :url => {:controller => "page_scraper", :action => "scrape"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field (:url) %>
  <%= f.submit "Scrape" %>
<% end %>

<%@domain ='default'%>
<%@date ='default'%>

<%= form_for @domain, :url => {:controller => "page_scraper", :action => "compare"} do |f| %>
  <%=select_tag 'domain', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.domain, u.domain] })%> 
  <%=select_tag 'date', options_for_select(@savedHTML.collect{ |u| [u.created_at, u.created_at] })%>
  <%= f.submit "compare" %>
<% end %>

<div class="subjects index">
  <h2>FGH Page Scraper</h2>



  <table class="listing" summary="Links list">
    <tr class="header">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>link</th>
      <th>Created at</th>
      <th>Updated at</th>
    </tr>
    <% @savedHTML.each do |page| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= page.id %></td>
      <td><%= page.domain %></td>
      <td class="center"><%= page.created_at %></td>
      <td class="center"><%= page.updated_at %></td>
      <td class="actions">
        <%= link_to("Delete", {:controller => 'page_scraper', :action => 'delete', :id => page.id}, :class => 'action delete') %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
class PageScraperController < ApplicationController
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'diffy'
    require 'htmlentities'

    def scrape

        @url = watched_link_params[:url].to_s
        puts "LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOG#{@url}"
        @page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
        coder = HTMLEntities.new
        @encodedHTML = coder.encode(@page)
        create

     end

     def index      
         @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.distinct.pluck(:domain)
      end

      def show
        @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.distinct.pluck(:domain)

      end

      def new
        @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.new


      end

      def create

        @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.create(domain: @url, html: @encodedHTML, css: '', javascript: '')

        if @savedHTML.save

          puts "ADDED TO THE DATABASE"

          redirect_to(root_path)
        else

          puts "FAILED TO ADD TO THE DATABASE"

        end
      end

      def edit

      end

      def upadate

      end

      def delete
        @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.find(params[:id])
      end

      def destroy
        @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.find(params[:id])
        @savedHTML.destroy
        redirect_to(root_path)
      end

     def compare

        @domain  = params[:domain].to_s
        puts @domain
        redirect_to(root_path)
        @timestamp

     end

    def watched_link_params

        params.require(:default).permit(:url)

    end

    def compare_params

        params.require(:domain).permit(:domain)

    end

end
```

Comment: Which view you are talking about? `index` or `show`? I can see that in your controller you are plucking out only the `domain` values which give you only string-domain. For ex. if you are having trouble in `index` action then you should replace `@savedHTML = ScrapedPage.distinct.pluck(:domain)` with `@savedHTML = ScrapedPage.all` or something so that it would return somekinf of ActiveRecord Relation

Comment: I have replaced index with `@savedHTML = ScrapedPage.all` and  show with `@savedHTML = ScrapedPage.find(params[:id])` and it works now but how would I make it display a value from my databse only once ?

Comment: What do you  mean under displaying the values only once? Maybe you need to replace `ScrapedPage.all` with `ScrapedPage.distinct`? I don't know your data structure so could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I want my table to display only unique values based on the domain tab in my view. Basically I have a database where i scrape some stuff of some pages and in the html table in my view I only want to display the domains only once  from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your controller you are saving only string-values to `@savedHTML` variable (`pluck` will give you only an array of attributes from given objects). Therefore you cant ask "some_string".domain because `String` class doesn't have a `domain` method.

If you have a `domain` method on `ScrapedPage` object then in your controller action (`index` or `show` - whatever you are dealing with) you should replace

```
@savedHTML = ScrapedPage.distinct.pluck(:domain)
```

with

```
@savedHTML = ScrapedPage.select(:domain).distinct
```

The latter will give you unique `ScrapedPage` objects based on `domain` value. Look [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct) for further info and examples.

**NB!** also a tip for refactoring:
Use strong parameters under `private` section. Also, if you have the same query in your controller twice in different actions then it is better to make it in [before_action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) like this:

```
class PageScraperController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_saved_html, only: %i[index show]

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def watched_link_params
    params.require(:default).permit(:url)
  end

  def compare_params
    params.require(:domain).permit(:domain)
  end

  def set_saved_html
    @savedHTML = ScrapedPage.select(:domain).distinct
  end
end
```